# Geomatry dash name change broke my game? Please help

Tags: geometry-dash

I went to the account page and changed my name the way that you are supposed to. But now whenever I open the game and go to my account the name is the same and says "something went wrong...". I can't open chests, go to my uploaded levels. Does it take a while for the name to change and update or did I mess my account up?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, this is a really easy fix. When you change your username at Account Management, there is one last step to complete. Open up your game, then click on the gear icon on the toolbar on the home page. Once clicked, a box will pop down, showing all the settings. Click the buttons in the following order: Account > More > **Refresh Login.** Enter in your new account username along with your password, and then your problem should be fixed.